# How to make Scratch Card effect in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've tried to use **mask** to make scratch card effect. It can't work. Maybe I use wrong function. Can someone tell me ? Here is the code.

```
struct ScratchCardView: View {
    @State var points: [CGPoint] = []
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Text")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .mask(MaskView(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: geometry.size)))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                points.append(value.location)
                            }
                    )
            })
        }
    }
    func MaskView(in rect: CGRect) -> some View {
        var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
        for point in points {
            path.addPath(Circle().path(in: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)))
            )
        }
        return path.fill(style: FillStyle(eoFill: true))
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scratch card effect?" You mean an image that is covered by a second image, and gets revealed as the user drags their finger over it, like a scratch-off lottery card?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a CALayer using you're view's bounds as its frame. Install the layer as your view's layer's mask.

Then install an image that's fully transparent in the mask's contents property. As the user drags with their finger, draw in any opaque color along the path of the user's finger with a series of circles at touch position. Turning part the image opaque will cause the mask to reveal that part of the image.

If instead you want a covering image that hides the content underneath, reverse the above. Create a `UIImageView` that covers the view you want to reveal (let's call it `coverView`.) Install a `CALayer` as that image view's mask, with a fully opaque image as its contents. As the user drags around, draw with `UIColor.clear` (transparent) into the mask's image. That will cause the `coverView` to be masked in those areas, revealing the image underneath.

Comment: Thank you. I will try.

Comment: This link covers using a `CALayer` as a mask pretty well: https://medium.com/@peteliev/layer-masking-for-beginners-c18a0a10743

Comment: That's very kind of you. I find that the tutorial import **Cocoa**. Actually I am a beginner and only learned Swift and SwifUI. If you know how to solve the problem by SwiftUI, that would be better.

Comment: I haven't ventured into SwiftUI yet.